# HTML5 animation Performance

Tags: javascript, html, macos, canvas

This question might be off topic but i am wondering why would the following code run much solver on macbook pro 2013 retina display then my old hp laptop. i use chrome browser on both devices. the reason i am asking this is because i developed a game using html5 and javaScript and the game runs much solver on the Mac

any advice?

```
window.onload=function(){
var demo = document.getElementById('demo');
var ctx = demo.getContext('2d');


var animObjects = [];
animObjects.push(new anim(ctx, 0, 90, 80,80, 'yellow', 3, 3));
animObjects.push(new anim(ctx, 20, 90, 80,80, 'red', 4, 0));


loop();

var e = new MouseEvent(ctx);
demo.addEventListener('mousemove', e.clickReporter, false);
function MouseEvent(ctx){
 this.clickReporter = function(evt){
        var mousePos = getMousePos(demo, evt);
        var message = 'Mouse position: ' + mousePos.x + ',' + mousePos.y;
        console.log(message);
        writeMessage(demo, message);
}
function getMousePos(demo, evt) {
        var rect = demo.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
          x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
          y: evt.clientY - rect.top
        };
}
function writeMessage(demo, message) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, demo.width, demo.height);
        ctx.font = '18pt Italic';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
        ctx.fillText(message, 10, 25);
}
}

function loop() {   
//ctx.clearRect(0, 0, demo.width, demo.height);
for(var i = 0, ao; ao = animObjects[i]; i++) {

    ao.update();
}
requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}


function anim(ctx, x, y, XSize,YSize, color, dx, dy) {
var me = this;

this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.XSize = XSize;
this.XSize = XSize;
this.color = color;
this.dx = dx;
this.dy = dy;

var bool = 0;

this.update = function() {
    ctx.clearRect(me.x, me.y, me.XSize, me.XSize);
    if (me.x < 0 || me.x > ctx.canvas.width-80){
        me.dx = -me.dx;
    }
    if (me.y < 0 || me.y > ctx.canvas.height-80){
        me.dy = -me.dy;
    }

    me.x += me.dx;
    me.y += me.dy;        
    render();
}
function render() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(me.x, me.y, me.XSize, me.XSize);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = me.color;
    ctx.fill();
}
return this;
}
}
```

Comment: Pretty simple. Slower computer/browser, slower animation. See the converse.

Comment: @Dude i would not say its solver then my 5 years old hp

Comment: computer_/browser_ Maybe there is some hardware-optimization issue in Chrome for Mac. I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your resolution is so high, (I'm assuming 3840x2400 due to Retina Display) it could be slowing down animation, games, ect.

You aren't the only one having this problem:

- [CSS3 keyframe animations sluggish on Retina display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420930/css3-keyframe-animations-sluggish-on-retina-display)
- http://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/1ps904/
- https://discussions.apple.com/message/20947370#20947370
- http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/n1eF-52M9AM

As a tip in the link going to apple.com, someone recommended checking out this:
http://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/vi9yf/set_your_retina_macbook_pros_resolution_to/

It allows you to switch between the native high DPI to a more common 1920x1200. You could try that out and see what happens! Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you, that what i did after some research, i lower the resolution and it worked